# PHP & JSON - Callback Function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays, json

I'm a JS newbie ... I've got a PHP page w/ a JavaScript function which makes a JSON call to a database server.  That JSON function returns an array, which I need to parse and do something with.  I understand the need for the callback (currently getting the undefined errors), but am confused as to the actual syntax.  Can anyone provide a bit of guidance?

Here's my JSON function in the PHP Page:

```
var GETDATA = function() 
  {
   $(document).ready(function()
   {
     $.getJSON('api.php', function(data) 
      {
     $.each(data, function(key, val) 
      {
        UpdateGraph(val.x, val.y, val.z);
      });
      });
   });
  };`
```

**The UpdateGraph function takes the variables and performs some further business logic

The api.php page connects to a database, grabs a recordset, and puts it into a JSON array.  the last line of that is

```
echo json_encode($arr);
```

I understand the asym flow of this, and that I need a callback function to fire when the data is received ... but I'm lost in how to make this happen.  Any guidance would be most appreciated.

Comment: That's a JavaScript function. Functions don't exist in JSON since it is a data exchange format. The overall code looks "ok" though you probably don't need to use a `.ready` callback. Is the function executed? What is the value of `data`? What are the `undefined` errors you get?

Comment: what triggers the call to the API? is it a click event? or on load?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, **JSON** is a format, not a language.

You already have the callback

```
$.getJSON('api.php', function(data)
```

**function(data)**  is your callback, and data is your returned data from php, inside of it you should add your code or what you want to do with the data.

```
 $.each(data, function(key, val){
        UpdateGraph(val.x, val.y, val.z);
 });
```

**$.each** will cycle through your **data** array and call the **UpdateGraph** function

Answer (score 0):

Your returned json object (data) should also have a key value relationship for each nested object inside "data". To put in a simple phrase...treat json object like a hash map with key/value

so say i have two object :object a and object b inside "data"

```
 $.each(data.a, function(key, val){
        UpdateGraph(val.x, val.y, val.z);
 });


 $.each(data.b, function(key, val){
        UpdateGraph(val.x, val.y, val.z);
 });
```

are valid